# !st.empty() is throwing runtime error if kept after &&

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl

`while(!st.empty() && nums[i%n] >= st.top()) st.pop();`

this code works but

`while(nums[i%n] >= st.top() && !st.empty()) st.pop();`

this isn't!

I was solving leetcode 503 (Next Greater Element II), my answer was

```
    int n = nums.size();
    stack<int> st;
    vector<int> nge(n, -1);

    for(int i = 2*n-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        while(nums[i%n] >= st.top() && !st.empty()) st.pop();
        if(i < n && !st.empty()) nge[i%n] = st.top();
        st.push(nums[i%n]);
    }
    
    return nge;`
```

but it didn't work unsless I put `!st.empty()` before `nums[i%n] >= st.top()`

Comment: That sounds like things are working right. If st.empty() is true, then it wouldn't be valid to access st.top(), since it doesn't exist. So you need to test st.empty first and short circuit evaluation will keep st.top() from being evaluated when there isn't one.

Comment: The logical AND and OR operators `&&` and `||` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). In short, with your shown code you can call `st.top()` even if the stack is empty, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What you describe is the behavior expected by the people qualified to answer your question. You apparently expected something else, but no one else knows what you are thinking, which makes it harder to give an answer targeting your specific misunderstanding. Why do you expect something different? Could you add an explanation of why you think `nums[i%n] >= st.top() && !st.empty()` should "work"? (Also, it would be good to add an explanation of what "didn't work" means in this context; what are the symptoms? This information would be more useful than "leetcode 503".)

Comment: *I was solving leetcode 503* -- Do not use Leetcode as a learning tool for C++.  The issue you had (short-circuit evaluation) is something discussed in the beginning chapters of any C++ book.  The questions at leetcode are designed for *experienced* C++ programmers who want to spend their spare time answering random puzzle questions.

Answer (score 2):

In the first version, you first check if the stack is not empty, and only then check if `nums[i%n] >= st.top()`. This is important because if the stack is empty, the `st.top()` will throw an error, and the program will crash.

In the second version, you first check if `nums[i%n] >= st.top()` , and only then check if the stack is not empty. In this case, if the stack is empty, the `st.top()` will throw an error and the program will crash before it even reaches the second condition `(!st.empty())`.

So it only works when you put `!st.empty()` before `nums[i%n] >= st.top()`

You have to make sure that the stack is not empty before you check the top element of the stack.

For more : [Short Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)